# Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'TextChannel' object has no attribute 'message'

Tags: python, discord.py

I am making a discord and i am working on its clear message command but it shows this

```
Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'TextChannel' object has no attribute 'message'
```

Here's the full code

```
from discord.ext import commands
class Clear(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot
    @commands.command()
    @commands.has_permissions(manage_messages=True)
    async def clear(self, ctx, amount=2):
        await ctx.channel.message.purge(limit=amount)
def setup(bot):
    bot.add_cog(Clear(bot))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't add the `.message` attribute to it as it doesn't exist within [TextChannel](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.TextChannel). [`ctx.channel.purge()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.TextChannel.purge) will work

```py
from discord.ext import commands
class Clear(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot
    @commands.command()
    @commands.has_permissions(manage_messages=True)
    async def clear(self, ctx, amount=2):
        await ctx.channel.purge(limit=amount)
def setup(bot):
    bot.add_cog(Clear(bot))
```